# How to show * instead of digits?

Tags: angular

I want to transform the output of the backend in my UI.

For example, when I receive `123456` from the backend, then in the UI it should be displayed as `***456`, or `1234` as `*234`.

Is there a in-built pipe available for this, or do I have to write a customized filter?

Comment: no there is no system define pipe available for this you need to create a user define pipe  for that you can also use directive for the same

Comment: Why not display it? If you load it unmasked from the backend the user can see the data by inspecting the network traffic anyway, so there's no security here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of only masking what the user sees, unless it's only for visual purposes. If you want that for security reasons, you need to make that transformation from your back-end.

However, what you're looking for is *masking* that output. The best and cleanest way to do that is using [Angular Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes). A pipe basically transforms the data it receives without changing its value, only the way it looks. You can take a look at this [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvmlij?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmask.pipe.ts) I found online, it suits your purpose just fine.

However keep in mind, if you're doing this for security purposes, it would make no sense whatsoever to only mask what the user sees. The data can still be accessed from what your API returns.